# Dynamically populate header text

Tags: json, extjs

My code in Extjs goes something like

```
{
    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
    header: 'Model1',
    sortable: false,
    resizable: false,
    format: '0,000.00',
    align: 'right',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'description',
    id: 'description'                         
}
```

Here the header is static. I want to change the header text also like `dataIndex` field. How can I do it?

Comment: You probably want to specify ExtJs version you're using...

Answer (score 0):

Look at `reconfigure` method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-method-reconfigure

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am using Grid. I am very new to this could you please help me in writing the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can to this.

Initially set header text blank or what you want.

and on the `gridstore.load` event get the column name and set text.

e.g.,

```
linelistunitstore.on('load',function(store)
{
    Ext.getCmp('usertype').setText(store.getAt('0').get('operationconditiontempunit'));    
});
```